# "Mourning", "whining" and "wailing"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I cannot differentiate the listed words below:

> - **Wail** 
>     to make a long, high cry, usually because of pain or sadness, or to make a sound like this
> - **Mourn** 
>     To feel or express deep sadness, esp. because of someone’s death
> - **Whine** 
>     If you whine, especially as a child, you complain or express disappointment or unhappiness repeatedly

Please consider that, in many dictionaries, they have not been dedicated for a specific purpose while they emphasize by the adverbs "usually" and "specifically" in their definitions; hence, I don't know whether using each one in a particular case would be natural or not!

For instance, I don't know which choice would be more idiomatic and natural in each case below:

> **(First scenario)** (informal case) 
>   **A:** Why are you ____________? 
>   **B:** Oh,  you don't know how much my leg hurts.
>
> **(Second scenario)** 
>   **A:** Did you know that Ana's father passed away last night. 
>   **B:** Seriously!!! What a catastrophe! I'm really worried about her! Have you heard of her since morning? Is she OK? 
>   **A:** She is not OK at all!! Keeps sitting at home crying and ____________
>
> **(Third scenario)** 
>   - Last night, I couldn't sleep whatsoever!  A cat was lying down on the wall  ____________ just behind my sleeping room's window.

Comment: mourning aka grieving

Answer (score 4):

*Wailing* is crying loud and long. (Or, by metaphor, some similar sound.) It's a little archaic; normally you say *crying* instead.

*Mourning* = *grieving*: being upset because someone died. (Or, by metaphor, some other tragedy.) It's an emotion, not a sound, although it probably involves crying a lot. It probably lasts for months or years.

*Whining* can be a sound, in which case it's high-pitched and thin and usually not loud. A noise from insects or machinery may be described as a *whine*. But when it's used for a person, it's insulting and dismissive: someone who's whining is a child, and their complaint is not justified, and they're only pretending to be upset. You'd never describe someone who's mourning as "whining".

In your first example, none of these words is likely. *Whining* would be insulting: "Why are you complaining for no good reason?" *Wailing* sounds archaic here, and *mourning* doesn't make sense. "Why are you crying?" is more likely, but a native speaker would probably say "What's wrong?".

In your second example, Ana is mourning, but the last sentence is about what she's *doing*, not how she's *feeling*. Also, it's introduced with "keeps ___ing", which implies a repeated action — and mourning is a continuing state, not repeated. So you probably want *wailing*. (It overlaps with *crying*, but that's OK.)

In your third example, the concept is *crying loudly*, so *wailing* is the right word.

Comment: Thank you @Anonymous; just in order to come to a conclusion, could you please tell me whether using **wail** in my first scenario souns so archaic that hearing it would make people I'm talking in shekespear time? :) I mean if it sounds quiet odd that I have to avoid using it?

Comment: I agree with everything here, except maybe the part about _whining_ being "unlikely". (Although I completely agree that, if used, _whining_ would be meant more as an insult than a question laced with empathy; _whining_ is rather common as a synonym for "incessantly complaining.") @A-friend - Yes, you are correct; don't use **wail** unless you want to sound Shakespearian.

Comment: *Wail* isn't *that* archaic. I'd use it if the meaning is particularly appropriate: if the person's cries are particularly long and loud. But if they're just crying a little, the meaning would be wrong.

Comment: For your first scenario, it would be unlikely someone was wailing about a hurt leg. They might be whining or whinging, but asking them that would be pretty rude, and show them you don't really think anything is wrong with them.

Comment: Thank you @Showsni; just does the word **"whine"** work in my second scenario or it sounds rude again?

Comment: No, never use whining about someone who is in mourning unless you want to come off sounding very cold and heartless! It would be like saying you can't understand why they are upset. "Crying and wailing" would fit (if they are crying loudly). If you wanted to be poetical and archaic you could use "beating her breasts" too. For your third example, you could also say the cat was yowling.

Comment: For the third example, the most common verb used to describe a very loud cat might be **yowling** rather than **wailing**, which is most often associated with humans, ghosts, or the wind, but seldom with non-human animals.

Comment: @Showsni: "beating her breast", not "breasts". This expression uses the old sense of *breast* meaning *chest*, not the new one meaning *mammary*.

Answer (score 1):

'Wailing' is a loud cry of anguish, of mental pain, such as that of a distraut mourner at a funeral.

'Mourning' is a state of being, it may be entirely calm, respectful and dignified, or it may involve wailing etc.

'Whining' is what little children do when they can't get their way, or what a dog does when it is locked up. It also covers similar behaviour by adults, which may be vocal or written.

Only 'Whining' fits with your first scenario.

Only 'Wailing' perfectly fits your second scenario, but in general she is "in mourning".

Your third scenario probably needs a different word, but *possibly* 'whining' might fit. Neither of the other two fit at all.

Comment: Right, whining can only go in 1). But it could be considered insensitive. I do think one can say that a cat is wailing. More expressive is: mewling or the charming word, caterwauling. :) I also think you can say to a kid, Why are you wailing? If you are what I call a "literary" speaker.